# 1Samuel 16,12 on David

Tags: tanach, king-david

According to the translation of *1Samuel* 16:12 of *The Koren Jerusalem Bible* it translates that David: "[was ruddy, with fine eyes, and good lookin](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.16.12?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi)".Some rabbinical comments, however, such as *Or Hachayim, Isaiah Horowitz, Rabbenu Bahya, Daat Zkenim*, *etc*. they believe that the Hebrew term admoni does not refer to the color of the hair, but to the cheeks of David.For example, *Or Hachaym* writes "[In *1Samuel* 16:12 the prophet describes David as admoni, red-cheeked, that is, warm-blooded](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.49.5.1?ven=Or_Hachayim,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk&vhe=On_Your_Way_&lang=bi)" (*Or Hachayim, *Gen**. 49.5.1). The red color (*admoni*) therefore does not refer to the hair  (*śear*) is not actually mentioned as in the specific case of Esau (*Gen*. 25,25), but to the cheeks, that is to the face (*a yin*) of David. In the Hebrew text we have: "[wehu admoni im-yepheh einayim wetov ro'i.](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.16.12)" However, I am not sure, and some notes say that the meaning is uncertain and in fact the official translations are conflicting. For example in *Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures*, he translates as follows: "[He was ruddy-cheeked, bright-eyed, and handsome](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.16.12?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi)". The question is: according to *1 Samuel* 16:12 does it refer to the color of the cheeks or of the hair?

Comment: I don't understand your question? You've brought a bunch of sources that argue the point?

Comment: As I wrote, I would like to know yours opinion on the term Admoni in 1Samuel 16.12. Does it refer to David's hair color or to David's cheeks? I think the passage is not about hair. Consequently he was not red-haired.

Comment: Are our opinions really that important to you? How will you assess a correct answer?

Comment: Isn't it legitimate to know your opinion?

Comment: It's legitimate but not a good format for this site.

Comment: "not a good format for this site" and why?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/

Comment: Ok, thanks. I understand.

Comment: Can you name the commentators that state it refers to his hair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://mg.alhatorah.org/Full/Shemuel_I/16.12#e0n6 goes through a number of commentaries and most of them imply that it is the physical makeup rather than the hair alone. Thus David was ruddy in general make up and showed a physical health and well being in general. This is similar to the way Eisav was considered. Note that Eisav was not circumcised as an infant because they worried that the extreme redness at birth implied that he could not be cut at eight days. Thus Admoni is a ruddiness due to the blood circulating rather than the color of the hair.

Comment: A thousand thanks. Interestingly, if that is indeed the case and red refers to skin, is there a possibility that śear in Genesis 25.25 means that he was actually hairy, but not necessarily red in color of hair? This too would need to be explored further.

Comment: @Ootsutsuki You could ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Ootsutsuki That is how I understand the verse. The diacritical notes to the verse break the "he was red" and "he was hairy" into two separate clauses. FWIW, I believe the term admoni always refers to skin color.

Comment: I agree with you!

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is that the term is more evocative of his nature and not his physical appearance.

Whilst the Metzudos Dovid explains somewhat ambiguously that "אדמוני" simply means:

> מראה אדום
>
> Of red appearance

Many commentaries view this redness as being emblematic of his nature, in other words pointing to that fact that he had a streak of red-bloodedness. The [Ohr HaChaim](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.16.12?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&p2=Or_HaChaim_on_Genesis.49.5.1&ven2=Or_Hachayim,_trans._Eliyahu_Munk&vhe2=On_Your_Way_&lang2=bi) you mentioned says expressly:

> ודוד טבעו חם כאומרו (ש"א טז) והוא אדמוני
>
> And Dovid's nature was hot (i.e. hot-blooded) like it says "And he was אדמוני".

This same descriptive feature is used for Esav in [Bereishis 25:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.25?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), to which [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.25?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.25.25.1&vhe2=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang2=bi) over there writes:

> אדמוני. סִימָן הוּא שֶׁיְּהֵא שׁוֹפֵךְ דָּמִים (בראשית רבה)
>
> אדמוני RED — a sign that he would always be shedding blood ([Genesis Rabbah 63:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.63.8?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_--_TE&lang=bi))

In fact the Midrash listed in Rashi points out that Shmuel was initially nervous of having Dovid annointed as king because he was worried that he would be likewise inclined to the murderous ways of Esav.

The [Malbim](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.16.12?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&p2=Malbim_on_I_Samuel.16.12.1&ven2=Sefaria_Community_Translation&vhe2=On_Your_Way&lang2=bi) begins by actually asking why is the attribute of being "אדמוני" - lit. "red" mentioned if it normally has negative connotations i.e. that of blood lust and anger. He therefore answers that the juxtaposition of writing "אדמוני" along with the fact that he was "bright-eyed and handsome", illustrates that whilst Dovid  was overcome by this sense of "redness" and nature to shed blood, on the other hand, it also shows his good side because he had beautiful eyes and good looks - thus it serves to demonstrate that his natural disposition was one that was sharp-sighted and good-natured - in other words he kept a measure of equilibrium despite his propensity for violence.

This theme is also explored by the [Shelah Hakadosh, Torah Shebichsav, Toldos, Torah Ohr 54](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Toldot%2C_Torah_Ohr.54?ven=Shney_Luchot_Habrit_by_Rabbi_Eliyahu_Munk&vhe=Shenei_Luchot_HaBrit,_based_on_Amsterdam,_1698_ed._Part_III&lang=bi) who also notes that same expression used by Esav.

> This אדמוני will eventually emerge purified and holy, a reference to the David who is also known as אדמוני. We read in Samuel I 16,12 that David is described as אדמוני עם יפה עינים וטוב ראי, "ruddy cheeked, bright-eyed and handsome." The first person to be described as אדמוני was Esau; it is therefore hardly a compliment to David to be similarly described. The essential difference is that whereas Esau was עין רע, represented all that is negative associated with the eye, David was the reverse, and is therefore described as יפה עינים. (Sefaria translation)

Comment: I agree. The fact remains that in the first translation The Koren Jerusalem Bible it is understood that David is red of hair, while in the Tanakh: The Holy Scriptures it is specified that his cheeks are of this color. The texts that we have both quoted agree that David was red in the cheeks not of hair.

Comment: Furthermore, like David, Solomon is similarly described as waʾadom "vermilion" that is dark red (Cant. 5,10). Rashi is equally keen to clarify: "I would explain the simple meaning of him, as praise of the beauty of a young man, when he is white and his face is ruddy" (Rashi, Cant. 5,10). It can be deduced that not even Solomon has red hair, red is the coloring of his face.

Comment: What makes you think that the Koren's translation is definitive?

Comment: As I have proven in the answer, the whole emphasis of אדמוני is not about the physical features so I don't understand why you are so keen to know the truth of his appearance?

Comment: Also where in that Koren translation do you see it as a reference to his hair?

Comment: Sorry, but if it's about the face (Ayin) how can it not relate to the physical characteristics? What are the cheeks, the face? As for Koren's translation, here it is: https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.16.12?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible since it does not mention the face, so deduces that it is the red of the hair in the same way that Esau. Shalom

Comment: I disagree just because it doesn't say ayin does not mean that it is referring to hair?!

Comment: אין מקרא יוצא מידי פשוטו. If it says his appearance was red, that's what it means. The commentators understand that this fact must have significance for it to be worthy of mention, but that in no way makes it only evocative.

Comment: @NT - I am not denying that point but the mefarshim don't go into detail into his appearance as they derive more about his character traits from that description.