# Where do we know Esav was a redhead?

Tags: parashat-toldot, esav, hair

I’ve heard my whole life that Esav and David were redheads. The question is where is this known from. The word that describes them as [אדמוני](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) seems to be translated as "ruddy" or "manly" by most.

Anyone know where a translation as redhead would be from?

Comment: The jastrow says it means reddish and specifically by hair. He quotes Y. Nedarim 36. But I can’t find what he’s talking about

Comment: Jastrow quotes examples, not prooftexts. It does appear [here](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Nedarim.1.1.14?vhe=The_Jerusalem_Talmud,_edition_by_Heinrich_W._Guggenheimer._Berlin,_De_Gruyter,_1999-2015&lang=bi) in yNedarim.

Comment: Doesn't "ruddy" mean "reddish"?

Comment: Hasn't this question been asked already?

Comment: If so feel free to link it

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/129138/1samuel-16-12-on-david — not exactly a duplicate, but very close.